# Simple Perl socket script hanging

Tags: performance, perl, sockets, tcp

I have a Perl script consisting of the following:

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl
 # Script name: socket.pl

 # Build socket:
 use IO::Socket;
 my $sock = new IO::Socket::INET (
                                  PeerAddr => '74.74.74.74',
                                  PeerPort => '1543',
                                  Proto => 'tcp',
                                 )
 or die "Could not create socket: $@\n"; 

 # Make a pipe-delimited string out of the four arguments:
 $data = "$ARGV[0]$ARGV[1]|$ARGV[2]|$ARGV[3]|$ARGV[4]";

 # Write to socket and immediately close:
 print $sock "$data";
 close($sock);
```

The problem starts to surface when the script gets called many times.  In a scenario where the script is getting called 60 times per minute, if I `pgrep` for `socket.pl`, I see 100 or 200 instances that have been "running" for up to 3 or 4 minutes.  The server to which they are writing appears to receive  `$data` immediately and on an exception free socket.

Given that I don't see any ostensible errors on the peer, why is this script lingering around even though it appears to have written to the socket?  Could the interpreter be bogging down or hitting some constraint or limit (the script is running on a very capable box so its not system limitations)?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks ok, at a glance. I would guess you're having an issue on the other end(server).

Comment: The peer correctly receives the message on an exception free socket, confirmed from peers logs (software/logs/source are open).  The peer then closes the socket from its end...but my perl script just hangs out, even though it too is (supposed to be) doing a socket close.  Yeah, it's truly weird.

Comment: What if you specify a timeout? Do you log the STDERR output of `socket.pl`? If it's blocking, assuming the args are small, I bet it's in `new`.

Comment: I know for certain it's not block at `new` because I can verify its socket operation completed (by viewing the logs of the box it's connecting to).   The socket operation completes, which makes me thing the `close($sock)` might be the defect.  When I do the update I'll note in this post whether that worked or not.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this will help, but you could try closing the socket using the `IO::Socket::INET`  itself: `$sock->close()` or `$sock->shutdown(2)`. Also try adding `exit(0)` at the end.

Comment: I'll put these in and re-test.  Out of curiosity, why isn't `close($sock)` good enough?

Comment: Not only is `close($sock)` good enough, it's not needed. Perl will do it automatically before exiting, and the system will do it should Perl not do it (e.g. in the event of a SEGFAULT).

Comment: Will Perl implicitly close it no matter what at the end of a script?  I.E. what if the TCP peer has not closed it or tries to write to it?